# Page Build Error while building a site with Jekyll

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I'm building a site portfolio using Jekyll. Currently I'm referencing DataOptimal through they GitHub page and YouTube channel.

I've customised my site but when pushing changes into Git, I encountered a Page Build Error message as follows:

> The page build failed for the `master` branch with the following error: A file was included in `_pages/project.md` that is a symlink or does not exist in your `_includes` directory. For more information, see
> https://docs.github.com/github/working-with-github-pages/troubleshooting-jekyll-build-errors-for-github-pages-sites#file-is-a-symlink.

I have accessed the link, and probably the most relevant suggestion based on the above error message is this:

> File is a symlink.
> This error means that your code references a symlinked file that does not exist in the publishing source for your site. To troubleshoot, search the file in the error message for include to see where you've referenced other files, such as {% include example_header.html %}. If any of the files you've referenced are symlinked, copy or move the files into the `_includes` directory.

So looking at my code under `_pages/project.md`:

```
{% include base_path %}
{% include group-by-array collection=site.posts field="tags" %}
{% for tag in group_names %}
    {% assign posts = group_items[forloop.index0] %}
    <h2 id="{{ tag | slugify }}" class="archive__subtitle">{{ tag }}</h2>
    {% for post in posts %}
        {% include archive-single.html %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I presume that the error is coming from `archive-single.html` so I went into `_includes` directory to check if the file is in, and it is in, so it exists.

So it turns out that maybe `archive-single.html` was not the issue. I can't seem to pinpoint where is the error to rectify it. Am I interpreting symlink wrongly?

Appreciate any inputs to assist on this.

Comment: The first two lines are also using the `include` tag, and don't list extensions making it look like the problem so I'd look there. If you include a repo link or list of files in the _includes directory it'd make it a bit easier to diagnose here. Symlink references here are likely part of a catch-all error message about why your file doesn't exist to include.

Comment: Hi Ross, that makes sense, but I couldn't find the base_path file or the group-by-array file  and I am not sure how to get those files. But anyway, I tried deleting the whole chunk and my site was able to publish. Maybe the code is not so essential, either that or there may be some downstream impact that I may come across. I'll cross that bridge when it comes to it. Thanks for your input.

Comment: No problem! A common place for files to hide in Jekyll is in the theme. See if you are using a theme by looking in your `_config.yml` for a `theme` field. The includes referenced here could be inherited from there.